# Include calculatorform example as custom widget without promotion?

Tags: qt, widget

I've build a collection of several widgets and successfully included them to QTDesigenr. But i can't figure out how to include
the calculatorform-example. It's an ui build widget after adding the collection interface I still can't compile it because of
obviously missing ui_calculatorform.h file.

What am I missing? Promoting the widget is no option, has to be Drag'n Drop.
Thank you for any hints.

Comment: Thank you stackoverflow-monkey...
Checked the project files and the necessary forms weren't included. Now all ui-files are in the testing environment and it works,
but I think thats not the "real" solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create ui_form.h from your form form.ui. Do,

```
   uic -o ui_form.h form.ui
```